# Criar um list de dict python

Tags: python, lista, dicionário, append

Possuo a seguinte função em python

```
def playersID(self, listDetals):
        listPlayersID = []
        tempDict = {}
        for x in listDetals:
            for y in x['result']['players']:
                tempDict.clear()
                tempDict['match_id'] = x['result']['match_id']
                tempDict.update(y)
                listPlayersID.append(tempDict)
        return listPlayersID
```

O parametro "listDetals" é uma lista de Dict e o retorno da função tambem é uma lista de Dicionario com um pedaço de listDetals em cada posição.
O problema esta no comando "append".

Toda vez que ele é chamado, ele preenche TODA a lista novamente, em vez de  apenas criar uma nova posição ao final dela. Alguem tem ideia do por quê disso?

Comment: Tente trocar `tempDict.clear()` para `tempDict = {}` e veja se funciona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você usa `tempDict.clear()` ele afeta a variável que também já foi colocada na lista, basta alterar para `tempDict = {}`.

```
def playersID(self, listDetals):
    listPlayersID = []
    for x in listDetals:
        for y in x['result']['players']:
            tempDict = {'match_id': x['result']['match_id']}        
            tempDict.update(y)
            listPlayersID.append(tempDict)
    return listPlayersID
```

Detalhe, `append()` vai adicionar sempre ao final da lista, nunca vai substituir toda a lista pelo novo elemento. Reveja seu código, de preferência use [unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html).

Comment: Muito obrigado! Troquei o tempDict.clear() para tempDict = {} e resolveu!